# $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] returning parent directory, not sub-directory

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, dns

To begin, let me explain the way this website is structured. I built a website for a client which is hosted on wpengine.com. For the sake of demonstration, let's say this website url is: sub-company.wpengine.com. They have pointed the domain http://company.com/sub-company/ at the wpengine website. In a php file in the root of the wpengine site is a redirect function which includes

```
$referrer = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
```

Rather than referrer being set to: http://company.com/sub-company/ it is set to: http://company.com/. I need it to return the former.

I'm not sure if something needs to be configured in WordPress, with the DNS, or the .htaccess. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: REQUEST_URI is always the url from the company.wpengine.com path like /example.html. If you intend to get the referer you have to use HTTP_REFERER

Answer (score 0):

echo $_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"].$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"];

[Example](http://hayageek.com/php-get-current-url/)